# dlmopen causes zmq error "Interrupted system call"

Tags: zeromq, dlopen

I'm trying to use **`dlmopen()`** in order to launch the same **`.so`** file with few instances.
Because I the shared object includes few static methods, I have to use `dlmopen()` in order to create due instances of it.
For each instance (all in the same thread,if it matters), in the constructor I use:

```
handle_ = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, "path_to_so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
```

and I get no errors, I'm even able to use `dlsym()` to invoke functions from the so file:

```
int (*function_name)(int, const char *);
function_name = (int (*)(int, const char *))(unsigned long)dlsym(handle_, "function_name");
```

The thing that happens is when I try to use any kind of "*zmq send*" method (the receive works well) I get:

> `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'zmq::error_t'`
>   `what():  Interrupted system call`

even after I terminate the object of the `dlmopen()` and the object that created them.

Has anyone encountered this kind of problem? I tried to change the flags of the `dlmopen()` with no luck.

This is the code for zmq_send():

```
    inline size_t send (const void *buf_, size_t len_, int flags_ = 0)
    {
        int nbytes = zmq_send (ptr, buf_, len_, flags_);
        if (nbytes >= 0)
            return (size_t) nbytes;
        if (zmq_errno () == EAGAIN)
            return 0;
        throw error_t ();
    }
```

Comment: Would you mind to post the complete MCVE-code? The zmq_send()-call is nowhere visible above, in the original post.

Comment: Did your problem persist if you change `send` function name by another? (for instance `my_awesome_send`?

Comment: It doesn't work, I have just changed the name

Comment: Have you tried to debug with gdb? I assume it works without errors of you leave out `dlmopen()` completely? You can run the program with and without `dlmopen()` under strace/ltrace/LD_DEBUG and compare results.

Comment: When you say _static method_ you mean _static variable_ or _static data?_ I mean  just _static methods_ don't make `dlmopen` necessary. (Note: exceptions and dll's often don't work well together. (To be precise, it is C++ and dll's. Or C++ and anything.))

Comment: I mean static data, it has some kind of static buffer, and i need few of them.

Comment: Is libzmq part of the .so you are opening? As mentioned above, could you try to identify the actual call within libzmq that is causing the EINTR? Or, if that's not feasible, use strace and provide the output? Thanks!